# To Show that $T$ is singular

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on a real vector space $\mathbb{R^n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $T^2=\lambda T$  for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then if $||Tx||>||x||$ for a non zero vector $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ , then $T$ is necessarily singular.

From the transformation given above, we can (?) see that $0$ is an eigen value for the transformation. Do we really need the condition  $``$if $||Tx||>||x||$ for a non zero vector $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$'' to establish  that $T$ is singular?

Comment: You need to exclude the possibility $T=\lambda I$.

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more, thank you

Comment: $T=\lambda I$ satisfies $T^2=\lambda T$ and is nonsingular, so you need some sort of extra condition to exclude this possibility.

Comment: I have checked it again for any typos. But I am afraid that there is not any error or any missing info.

Comment: @Alec Diaz-Arias. Let's suppose, $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$, Then we will have $A^2-\lambda A$ = $0$; which implies $0$ will be an eigen value of $A$. Then $T$ is obviously singular. In that case, I didn't even use the condition given. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: As Chappers says you need to exclude the possibility of $T=\lambda I$. I suspect the condition $\|Tx\|>\|x\|$ is supposed to rule this case out, so you are presumably missing the condition on $\lambda$ like $|\lambda|\le 1$.